# php loop breaking down my css look

Tags: php, css, twitter-bootstrap-3

I am using an while loop and i want to generate the output in a well formatted look like a portfolio my code is here i just dont know what is breaking it down

```
<div class="container">

    <div class="row">
    <?php 
    while($fetch=mysqli_fetch_assoc($run)){
    ?>
    <div class="col-sm-3 col-xs-6">
                <a href="#">
                    <img class="img-responsive portfolio-item" src="~admin/uploadsthumbs/<?php echo $fetch['daily_img'];?>" alt="">
                </a>
    </div>
    <?php
    }
    ?>                              
    </div>

</div>
```

However the desired output which i want to have is like in the link below in the Related Project sections.
https://blackrockdigital.github.io/startbootstrap-portfolio-item/

Comment: the problem is, that you have an unknown column-count, but assign a special width via css. So bootstap expects 4 columns, but you might have 5 or many more. This breaks the layout.

Comment: You could make it a `ul` instead. Or make a manual row-break every 4th column.

Answer (score 0):

use this code:

```
<div class="container">

<div class="row">
<?php 
while($fetch=mysqli_fetch_assoc($run)){
echo '
<div class="col-sm-3 col-xs-6">
            <a href="#">
                <img class="img-responsive portfolio-item" src="~admin/uploadsthumbs/'.$fetch['daily_img'].'" alt="">
            </a>
</div>';
}     ?>                      
</div>
```

Comment: where's the difference? Why should this solve the problem??

Answer (score 0):

It might be your query result ($run) or class in the img tag.

If it is displaying the image, it is not the $run but the class in the img tag or bootstrap is not present in your script else it is the $run.

Enjoy coding for this is the fun of it.